# HelloJS + AngularJS - Async call to login function - oAuth

Tags: jquery, angularjs, oauth, hello.js

I am trying to implement HelloJS in my AngularJS app. What I understood
from documentation of HelloJS is that, to authenticate call login function,

```
hello("google").login().then(function(){ });
```

And then listen to 'auth.login' event, which will give you object returned from auth service, like below

```
hello.on('auth.login', function(authResponse){

        hello(authResponse.network).api( '/me' ).then(function (returnedUser){

            console.log(returnedUser);
            console.log(authResponse);
      });
    });
```

I don't want to listen to this event, I want to wait for response from auth server so that after then I can start my session in the application.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?
It should be more like $q deferred calls in jQuery.

Thanks
Fahad Mullaji

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I gave up on HelloJS library. 
Now I am using Google oAuth Javascript Client Library.
Check out this link...

https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this. I haven't yet used HelloJS, but I did see that it uses Promise/A+ and not $q (which is AngularJS specific.) Most likely you are not getting the digest cycle integrated with the external promise system.